# How to retrieve the value of a nested map using the value of the first map?

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, hashmap, pattern-matching

I have a map of entries of type Map[String, String] and a lookup map of type Map[String, Map[String, String]]. My goal is to look in the first map for a match in the second map, once I have a key match I have to replace the value in the first dictionary with the look up of the second dictionary. The example will clear things up.

I've come up with an algorithm so far but I am getting a strange answer of Some(e) and Some(t).

The first entry map is the following:

```
val entries = Map("fruit" -> "aaa", "animal" -> "bbb", "person" -> "jjj")
```

The second map is the following:

```
val lookup = Map("fruit" -> Map("ccc" -> "orange", "aaa" -> "apple"),
                 "animal" -> Map("zzz" -> "dog", "bbb" -> "cat"))
```

The result I am expecting is the following (Note: "person" was correctly not included in the result as there is no match for it):

```
val result = Map("fruit" -> "apple", "animal" -> "cat")
```

The algorithm I came up with is the following:

```
val res = for{ (k, ev) <- entries 
      lv <- lookup.get(k).get(ev)} yield (k, lv)
```

this algorithm gives me the following result and I have no idea why:

```
Map(fruit -> e, animal -> t)
```

Where is the e and t coming from?

Comment: @jwvh sorry for the confusion. I edited my question a few times and forgot to edit the title to reflect my changes. I hope the title is a bit clearer now!

Comment: The answers below will get your code to run as you expect, but i would like to suggest you try to find a different way to write it.
IMO, It's very concise but heavy with details that are very confusing - and your question is an example of this.  I suspect this is due to primitive obsession (https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession)
This is an opinion, not a fact.
If it were my code, i would try to rewrite it to be clearer, even at the cost of greater verbosity.
This is just a friendly suggestion, not a criticism.

Comment: @nathang that's a great point! Unfortunately I am not very familiar with scala as this is my third day using it. Any chance you can point me towards a solution or scala library/method that would allow me to refactor this to be more explicit?

Comment: no real library because frankly i don't really understand your use case. looking at your inputs and desired outputs, how is the collection of pairs you define as entries a map, philosophically? where do you use it's mappishness?
because if you have a collection of pairs, and a map from pair to result string, the code becomes much clearer and the inputs and outputs stay the same, data-content wise, as far as i can tell.
the general idiom in scala, regardless of this specific example, is to use case classes with helping methods that wrap the data types you want to abstract over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break it down into its constituent parts.

```
for {
  (k,v1) <- entries
  submap <- lookup.get(k)
  v2     <- submap.get(v1)
} yield (k,v2)
//res0: immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(fruit -> apple, animal -> cat)
```

Not sure where the `e` and `t` are coming from in your error output.

---

OK, I figured it out. `lv <- lookup.get(k).get(ev)` is iterating through every letter of `"apple"` and `"cat"` respectively, but as there can be only one key->value pair for each key in a `Map`, only the final letter is retained.

Comment: can you explain why lookup.get(k).get(ev) returns a string that I am mistakenly iterating over? If lookup is a map of string to map wouldn’t calling .get return a map that I can call .get on again?

Comment: `lookup.get(k)` returns an `Option[Map[String,String]`. If the `Option` is `None` then the following `.get(ev)` will throw an exception. If the `Option` is `Some(m)` then the `.get()` will unwrap it and apply the value of `ev` to it. In other words, the value of `ev` is given to the unwrapped `Map` as a key for retrieving the associated value, which is a `String` that gets sent to the generator (the `<-` part) which treats it as a sequence of `Char` values to be iterated and assigned to `lv`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
val res = for{ 
    (k, ev) <- entries
    l1 <- lookup.get(k)
    l2 <- l1.get(ev)
} yield { 
    (k, lv)
}
```

Problem Explanation:

```
lookup.get(k).get(ev) //this returns a String <- reason: not known

x <- "apple" //x is now a List[Char] -> List('a','p','p','l','e')
```

Now:

```
map += ("animal" -> 'a')
map += ("animal" -> 'p')
map += ("animal" -> 'p')
map += ("animal" -> 'l')
map += ("animal" -> 'e')
map += ("fruit" -> 'c')
map += ("fruit" -> 'a')
map += ("fruit" -> 't')
```

Will result in:

```
Map("animal" -> 'e', "fruit", 't')
```

Comment: Solution throws if `entries` contains a key not found in `lookup`.

Comment: @Iprakashv doesn’t lookup.get(k) return a map? Therefore lookup.get(k).get(ev) should return a value of that map right? Why does it return a string?

Comment: It is somehow returning String, try it yourself. Updating my answer.

Comment: @jjaguirre394 lookup.get(k) returns an Option[Map[T]] so I do not know why .get(ev) on an Option returns the value of the key of the map inside. Maybe some implicit, I need to check.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `yield` explains why this happens: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

The page, in Example 2, states:

```
for(x <- c1; y <- c2; z <- c3) yield {...}
is translated into
c1.flatMap(x => c2.flatMap(y => c3.map(z => {...})))
```

Therefore your comprehension translates to:

```
entries.flatMap({case (k, ev) => lookup.get(k).get(ev).map(lv => (k, lv)) })
```

The key here is that each of "apple" and "cat" are strings which `map` is being done on (i.e. you are iterating over each character of those words). Since a `Map` is being updated with `("fruit" -> "a") ... ("fruit" -> "e")`, only `(fruit -> e)` is apparent and the final result is what you saw:

```
Map(fruit -> e, animal -> t)
```

**Some ways to get the intended result:**

```
for{ (k, ev) <- entries ;lv <- lookup.get(k)} yield (k, lv.get(ev).get)
```

Or avoid chained comprehensions altogether, and just use a regular `map`:

```
entries.map({case (k, v) => (k, lookup.get(k).get(v))})
```

Both of these result in `Map(fruit -> apple, animal -> cat)` but note that these solutions don't handle the case where `get` returns a `None` (i.e. the lookup map is missing that key)

Comment: Solution throws if `lookup` sub-Map `lv` has no `ev` key entry.

Comment: yes, that needs to be handled additionally - was giving examples that can be starting points

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following approach for getting the output

```
val output = entries.map{
  case (k,v) =>
    k -> lookup.get(k).flatMap(_.get(v)).getOrElse(v)
}
```

This will fetch you the output as

```
output: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(fruit -> apple, animal -> cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline Solution :

```
val res =  entries.flatMap(e => lookup.get(e._1).flatMap(_.get(e._2).map(e._1->_)))
```

Output :

```
res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(fruit -> apple, animal -> cat)
```